# URL based locale detection in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 3 I used to get the locale detected, based on the first segment of the request URL.

`application/config/application.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Supported Languages
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These languages may also be supported by your application. If a request
| enters your application with a URI beginning with one of these values
| the default language will automatically be set to that language.
|
*/

'languages' => array(
    'en',
    'de',
    'fr',
),
```

So I can define a Route

```
Route::get('foo', function() {
    echo 'Foo';
});
```

and have it accessed via:

```
GET /en/foo
GET /de/foo
GET /fr/foo
```

Laravel 4 removes this feature.

Can I get this behaviour back?

I tried to manually implement it, but since I want it on every Request, I don't want to specify the language variable in every route (The Route above should work with my implementation). Here is my solution:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $language = Request::segment(1);

    if(in_array($language, Config::get('cms.available_languages')))
    {
        App::setLocale($language);
    }

    // Since locale is already set, 
    // I want to remove the language from the request URL (/en/foo => /foo)
    // So I can route via Route::get('foo', ...)
    $request->removeSegment(1);
}
```

But there is no way I know of to remove the language from the request URL, so I get 404, because en/foo is not specified.

What can I change to get this to work?

Comment: Do you always want to remove language from URL after detecting and setting locale?

Comment: I just tried to remove the language from URL for the `Route`s, but Mikes answer solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this forum post: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=7458

Here, we are simply detecting the language by picking up the URI prefix, and then applying it to a `group` of `Route`s.

Then, to compile those URLs for your Views, you would simply used Named Routes.

To me, it is the best way of going about it for now.

Comment: Group Routes will do it for now, this prevents me from coding language support in every route. Thanks!